# Print ancestor recursive function logic

Tags: c++, algorithm, tree, binary-search-tree

I need to implement this recursive void function that will print the ancestor of a given element (x), there are other ways, but I am curious what is wrong with my logic?

For example if we want to find the ancestor of C: it will print B A since 
C is child of B and B is child of A

Logic: we keep traversing until we find the element X, and then we hit the base case thus we utilize the stack to print the stack elements which will be the parents basically

Here is my code assume we have pointers to parent and everything for BST is provided:

```
void ancestor (BinaryNode * root, int x)
{

   //no need to check null assume x exist in the  BST
   if(root->data==x)
      return;
   if(root->data>x)
   {
      ancestor(root->left,x)
   }
   else
   {
      ancestor(root->right,x)

   }
   cout<<root->data<<endl;
}
```

Comment: It's unclear what your problem is. What is it doing and what do you expect it to do? From looking at the code, it looks like it will print the tree beginning at the parent of X and printing up to the root node. However, you probably want to put some null checks in.

Comment: make the problem statement clear with an example.

Comment: Done:  we are assuming the node exist thats why i didnt put any. the functions basiccally prints the ancestor of a given node

Comment: Please check your code, there are several typos and it's hard to read withoout proper formatting :)

Comment: Do your nodes have pointers to the parent?  This is not clear from the code you posted.

Comment: yes we assume they do @ThomasMatthews

Comment: If your nodes have pointers to the parent node, then follow the parent links.  No need for recursion.